# Counting number of plotted points in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

The data file contains values in the following format:

```
0 0 50
0 1 70
1 0 40
1 1 70
2 0 110
2 1 60
3 0 60
3 1 120
4 0 50
4 1 50
5 0 70
5 1 70
```

This is a code snippet from my gnuplot script:

```
plot 'file' using ($3 > 100 && $2 == 0 ? $1 : 1/0): 3 with points pointtype 1,\
     'file' using ($3 > 100 && $2 == 1 ? $1 : 1/0): 3 with points pointtype 2
```

Can someone suggest a way to count the number of plotted points of each pointtype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is relatively easy to do by setting a counter, then do `counter = counter + 1` when your condition is satisfied (I've removed the style for compactness):

```
minval = 100; count1 = 0; count2 = 0
plot 'file' using ($3 > minval && $2 == 0 ? (count1 = count1 + 1, $1) : 1/0):3, \
'file' using ($3 > minval && $2 == 1 ? (count2 = count2 + 1, $1) : 1/0):3

gnuplot> print count1, count2
1 1

minval = 50; count1 = 0; count2 = 0
plot 'file' using ($3 > minval && $2 == 0 ? (count1 = count1 + 1, $1) : 1/0):3, \
'file' using ($3 > minval && $2 == 1 ? (count2 = count2 + 1, $1) : 1/0):3

gnuplot> print count1, count2
3 5
```